# How to create the docker0 bridge in another network namespace then the default one?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-network, linux-namespaces

On a server I have an environment with different network namespaces that are created with the command `sudo ip netns add ns_name`. The physical interfaces of the server get assigned to different namespaces, in the "default" network namespace remains no physical interface.

On startup the docker daemon creates the docker0 bridge in the "default" network namespace. How to tell docker to create the docker0 bridge not in the default one but in one of the ones created by me?

Comment: You can start by modifying the systemd unit with `NetworkNamespacePath=/run/netns/ns_name`. This use to just work for me but now I have some issues starting containers so I'll post an answer if I get a full solution

Answer (score 0):

My system is a (2023) recent install of Archlinux, but these instructions should be similar to your distribution:

Make sure docker is stopped when you start this:

```bash
systemctl stop docker.socket
systemctl stop docker.service
```

Edit your docker systemd unit file, you can find it via `systemctl status docker.service`

> ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
> Loaded: loaded (**/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service**; disabled; preset: disabled)

Modify the `[Service]` part of the unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`:

```ini
[Service]
Type=notify
# This tells systemd to run dockerd in the network namespace
NetworkNamespacePath=/run/netns/ns_name
# This is the original docker command, it caused some issues for me
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
# This is the replacement if the default exec doesn't work
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// 
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

Now refresh the configs and start docker with

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

If you're lucky, you can now try running a docker container and it will just work. There's a bit of weird shenanigans going on so you might get an error whenever you start any container like the one below:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/sbin/tini": stat
> /sbin/tini: no such file or directory: unknown

This error appears to be from a misconfiguration between containerd and docker.
Open the `containerd` unit file and replace its `ExecStart` with the following:

```ini
ExecStart=/usr/bin/containerd --config=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
```

This will tell containerd to use docker's configuration and your containers should work after you reload the configs restart all the services.
Frankly, it is easier to just reboot the machine at this point.

As for what this does, we get an interesting series of effects.

- The `docker` executable talks to `dockerd` via a unix socket, so it does not matter what namespace you run `docker` or `docker-compose` commands from, as long as the socket is accessible.
- `containerd` is running in the default network namespace, which has all of the proper cgroups to create containers.
- `dockerd` is running inside your namespace, so it will create all network interfaces inside this namespace and all container networks will be generated inside this namespace by default.

As a final note, unless you setup a service to create your network namespace on boot, you will probably want to leave docker disabled and have a startup script create the namespace and then start docker.
In addition, you may need to run `chattr +i` on your unit files to prevent updates from overwriting your config changes.

Comment: As of systemd 254, you also need to set `PrivateMounts=no`, since `NetworkNamespacePath` now implies `PrivateMounts=yes` by default. Otherwise, you get the dreaded "failed to create shim task" error.  I've also found that I don't need to modify the ExecStart command-line for either service (on Debian bookworm).

Comment: Also, rather than editing the .service files directly, you can use `systemctl edit docker.service` to add overrides that will be preserved across package upgrades.